# PHP - Read Returned Array from Function

Tags: php, arrays, class, function, loops

```
require('mq_class.php');
print_r(Minequery::query("64.31.24.137"));
```

returns:

```
Array ( [serverPort] => 25565 [playerCount] => 6 [maxPlayers] => 40 [playerList] => Array ( [0] => Uthly [1] => epson8 [2] => CheeseBricks [3] => Truth92 [4] => zerokhaos [5] => plainlazy95 ) [latency] => 25.8100032806 )
```

Now, how would I read, say `serverPort` (a variable) or `playerList` (which is an array)?

I've done PHP for a while now, I guess I know only a little amount.

Comment: By the way: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = Minequery::query("64.31.24.137");
echo $data['serverPort'];
echo $data['playerList'][0];
```

Read up on [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: You're a life saver!

Alright, in 12 minutes (time restriction) I will make this the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
$array = Minequery::query("64.31.24.137");
echo $array['serverPort']; // will print 25565
print_r($array['playerList']); // will print the subarray info
```

Comment: Thanks! Someone else beat you to the punch, but that answer is correct as well.

Comment: +1 The answer I was putting together was identical to yours except without comment. LOL, these questions are a race. 3 answers, all of which are almost identical all arriving in less than a minute of each other. My answer would have been in here too but I saw the notice come up right before clicking submit.

Comment: @ghbarratt lol, you're right dude. Very few seconds and all right answer. I think this is an amazing community. Will we race again next time? :p

Answer (score 0):

```
$serverDetails = Minequery::query("54.31.24.137");
$serverPort = $serverDetails['serverPort'];
echo $serverPort; //25565
$playerList = $serverDetails['playerList'];
print_r($playerList); //Array ( [0] => Uthly [1] => epson8 [2] => CheeseBricks [3] => Truth92 [4] => zerokhaos [5] => plainlazy95 )
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes for `playerlist`!

Comment: A bit round about and `$playerList = $serverDetails[playerList];` will fail.

Comment: @ComFreek If you see silly mistakes, edit the question and correct them, you'll earn rep!

Comment: @fredley: Okay, next time I'll do it ;)